# first who, second why

Tags: support, chat, suspension

I'm currently suspended from chat, for at best, a slightly not nice comment, for 12 hours, with no notice, or explanation. I'm just dying to know who did it, and why they did it.

FYI mod team, it's "not nice" to suspend for 12 hours with no reason. Kthnx

The flag was for saying "and their assholes" fyi - "their" being Skeptics stack as a whole.

Comment: Could this perhaps be edited to include more context? Also, it seems unlikely that the identity of the person who flagged you will be revealed (nor should it be).

Comment: @Adamant i was flaged the post was removed, i received a 30 min suspension, a mod personally added a 12 hour suspension, that mod should be named and state his reason.

Comment: Names are not something that routinely get disclosed. Precisely because people will try to *ruin their day*.

Comment: @ArtOfCode well Mods are not random users, so Mods should have to own up to suspensions they hand out, and have actual reasons why, especially if they are off site mods.

Comment: There will be a reason or reasons why, yes, and you may well be informed of those. I doubt you'll be told who did it.

Comment: @ArtOfCode please read transcripts sketpics se is called names all the time in our chat. kthnx bia feel free to suspended every other user for 12 hours as well.

Comment: I'm not the mod who suspended you, FYI. But there's still a difference between jokingly poking fun at other sites, and straight-up abusing them.

Answer (score 23):

You were suspended for posting inappropriate content by a mod who has been entrusted by the powers that be (read: the community team) to make that judgment.

In my opinion, it was merited. And for your sake, I really don't think you want to discuss the specifics publicly.

Wait 12 hours, come back to chat, and try to be nicer in the future.

Comment: i dont like arguing with the CM's since you guys run the show, but out of all the suspensions i've ever received this was the LEAST warranted of the bunch. I know this is a privacy thing so feel free to vent any and all of my business to the SFF as a whole on this issue to make it clear why i was suspended for 12 hours for a flippant remark. Im not trying to cause trouble here, but ive never seen this response in 2 years on site, for a comment ive made at least 10 times on site. It was either targeted or done in bad faith.

Comment: @Himarm Today, suspended. Oct. 20, suspended. Oct. 10, suspended. This is just the past month, and this isn't even counting flags (of which I have seen many, and I actively avoid chat flags like the plague to give communities the chance to police themselves). If you keep saying provocative stuff, you are going to keep getting suspended. You're lucky too, if it were me handling the flag I'd have suspended you for a lot longer than 12 hours. Try being nice, and be happy that it was just 12 hours this time maybe?

Comment: oh yeah my hillary meme's, oh man CTR is here /sigh.

Comment: @Himarm you are missing the point. The community -- other users -- find what you are posting to be inappropriate. We have a [be nice policy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) that falls afoul of. I know this has been explained to you in the past, yet you persist on making excuses for your actions. If you can't play nice, you won't be allowed to play at all. I have no idea what "CTR" is, but unless it stands for "Can't Tolerate Rules" then it has zero bearing on what you're being punished for.

Comment: @jmac - don't know what THIS conflaguration was about, but have you suspended the mod who posted Trump death theats in chat yet? How about all the non-mod-users who have been posting offensive political chat messages for the last many months, as long as they weren't anti-Hillary? It'd be nice if you (CMs) actually lived by the principles you profess to find important, universally, and not only when you find convenient.

Comment: Not sure entirely who you're referring to, @DVK... But if it's the person I think it is, he got warned and hopefully knows better than to do it again. Which is a good thing to aim for when being warned, I think.

Comment: @Shog9 - based on the wording of your comment, I suspect it was not the same person, sorry. Well, the last death threat still undeleted was in October, but the not-nice comments about politicians are much more recent.

Comment: @DVK-in-exile If you have a complaint about the actions of a mod that you want the CM team to look in to please use the [contact us](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/contact) form and include all relevant details. We will look into it and see if any action should be taken. That said, what someone else said in chat has nothing to do with Himarm's suspension. If you have separate issues, bring it up in the proper way. Publicly casting aspersions on mods will not end well for you because even if you were right in a single case, you are causing more harm with the way you're going about it.

Comment: @jmac - yes, yes I know. A mod posting death threats (or even plain not nice messages) is fine with you, me bringing it up will "not end will for me". Thank you for proving my point. HINT: if you want to avoid harm, don't only moderate and police "be nice" one political way.

Comment: @DVK-in-exile Anyone -- mod or otherwise -- posting death-threats is not okay with me. But here's the thing, comments on an entirely separate issue is *not* the way to handle it if it happens. Send an e-mail using the contact form and I promise that we will look in to it. If you cared that much about it, you would have sent the e-mail rather than adding more cryptic comments which do nothing to solve the problem and only serve to stir up trouble. Send an e-mail or don't, but I will actively delete comments regarding this because it isn't the right format for the discussion.

Comment: @jmac - last time I sent email to CMs about a moderator doing something bad, NOTHING happened (even the offensive chat comments didn't get deleted). Sorry, but i'm done with that route. If it ain't a public complaint, it gets ignored, in my experience. (as a matter of fact, Shog pretty much alluded to that earlier, to the point that -a as far as I understood his point -  CMs mostly care about things that cause them annoyance and bother).

Comment: @jmac - BTW, the only reason i singled out mods was because in my opinion, mods are supposedly held to higher standards (ref: year old events on SFF). Regular users posted pretty not-nice political stuff all over chat, non-stop, for months.

Comment: @DVK-in-exile Let me be very clear: if you have a legitimate complaint about a mod (or a CM) use the contact form and live with the result. That's the process. If you do not like the results of that process, that does **not** give you the right to start publicly calling people out. Send another e-mail or don't, but stop making public accusations because they are not nice and against the rules.